# Where to combine database data with file system data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, structure

I am creating a .NET Core Web API application where people can find building plans for houses.

The application has a database table which contains information like address, zip, city and an ID.

The PDFs are stored on the File System and are grouped in folders with the same ID as in the Database.

This is my current Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<BuildingplanDto>>> Get(
    [FromQuery] string street,
    [FromQuery] string city,
    [FromQuery] string housenumber)
{
    //Retrieve building plan info from database
    List<Buildingplan> buildingplans = await _BuildingplanService.FindAsync(street, city, housenumber);

    List<BuildingplanDto> buildingplanDtos = new List<BuildingplanDto>();
    BuildingplanDto buildingplanDto;
    foreach (Buildingplan buildingplan in buildingplans)
    {
        //Map database entity to Dto
        buildingplanDto = _mapper.Map<Buildingplan, BuildingplanDto>(buildingplan);
        //Add folders from the filesystem to the Dto
        buildingplanDto.Folders = _documentService.GetFolders(buildingplan.DossierId);
        buildingplanDtos.Add(buildingplanDto);
    }

    return Ok(buildingplanDtos);
}
```

However this code doesn't feel right; There is too much logic in the Controller which I want to put somewhere else. I don't know where to put it though.

Could anyone give me a direction where to put this logic? I am also open for other tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to layer your application, where each layer has a specific purpose.  The most basic layering is UI-Logic-Data, but there are other more advanced architectures as well - e.g. https://morphological.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/5-layer-architecture/ (a blog post of mine).

Think of the API controller as the UI - it should only be responsible for handling the API request and providing back a response; the "heavy lifting" of pulling together the data that goes into the response would be done elsewhere.

For example, a **basic** 3-layer model could look like this:

1. API layer - is responsible for handling external API requests.
2. Logic layer - is responsible for making decisions such as orchestrating various calls, enforcing business rules and so on.
3. Data / Service layer - is responsible for fetching data, e.g. from a database, file system or external API.